# Retrieve specific days of the week within a given range from Linq?

Tags: c#

Is it possible given a date range to pull out specific days of the week and display their dates?

So, if my date range is from 08/17/2012 to 09/17/2012 is it possible, using linq to pull out say, all of the Thursdays and Tuesdays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can determine the number of days between the dates, then generate all the dates and filter on the days of the week you're interested in.

```
var start = DateTime.Parse("08/17/2012");
var end = DateTime.Parse("09/17/2012");
int numberOfDays = end.Subtract(start).Days + 1;
var daysOfWeek = new[] { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday };

var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays)
                      .Select(i => start.AddDays(i))
                      .Where(d => daysOfWeek.Contains(d.DayOfWeek));
```

Comment: Don't use Days but TotalDays property of TimeSpan. Days is just the days component of it (e.g. for a timespan of 1 week and 2 days, returns 2, while TotalDays returns 9 days).

Comment: @digEmAll I don't think that's accurate. `TotalDays` returns a `double` and represents the whole and fractional days. `Days` returns an `int`, thus ignoring any fractional portion. For example, for `TimeSpan.FromDays(9.5)`, `Days` = 9, `TotalDays` = 9.5.

Comment: Yes, I checked and you're right. I apologize, what I said applies for example for the other components like hours, minutes and so on but not for days since it's the biggest component of TimeSpan :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var start = new DateTime(2012, 8, 17);
var end = new DateTime(2012, 9, 17);

var daysToChoose = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday };

var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(end - start).TotalDays + 1)
                        .Select(d => start.AddDays(d))
                        .Where(d => daysToChoose.Contains(d.DayOfWeek));
```